# How to subtract the size of a height already defined by an element style?

Tags: css

A div has an element style with a height of 20px.

Is it possible to create a class in CSS that gets this height already defined (20px) and subtract by 5px?

Note: The size of the height defined in the style of the element is created by a JS that I do not have access to and its value is dynamic.

```html
<div class="main" style="height: 20px;"></div>
```

```css
.main {
  /* ? */
}
```

Comment: set a max-height ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, but how do I get the height value set in the element?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `5px` of padding (or border) to decrease the content area and use a negative margin to rectify the padding added:

```css
.main {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
  background:red content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" style="height: 80px;"> some text here</div>
content after this
```

Comment: Nice, never was thought i can pass `box-sizing` in background. +1

Comment: @yayapro it's not box-sizing but background-clip: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

But you can create a child and set it height to `calc(100% - 5px)`.

codepen: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PvrpXz

if you don't want to add a child, you can also use border-bottom to `5px solid white` (and also `box-sizing: border-box` ) to make element look 5px shorter.